# PopSQL and Command Line Client returns different result

Tags: mysql, command-line, popsql

So originally my question was - 'How to prevent duplicates between two columns, using one table?'
I tried to check the same query via Command Line and it returned different result.
Maybe I need to change the SQL editor? What is the problem here in general and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Query:

```
SELECT 
    c1.city,
    c1.customerName,
    c2.customerName
FROM
    customers c1
INNER JOIN
    customers c2
    ON c1.city = c2.city 
    AND c1.customerName > c2.customerName
WHERE c1.city = 'Auckland'
ORDER BY
    c1.city;
```

[image: Command Line Result]

[image: PopSQL Result]

Edit: fixed the tables results

Comment: PopSQL returns the same result @nbk

Comment: sorry i posted a new answer.

Comment: @nbk I forgot to mention that I tried different operators including `<>`
still duplicates there https://imgur.com/Hhmchf3

Comment: then show me the original data, because you see in the example that works with <>

Comment: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2sHwH5Bv8VtwouhJqViGp6/0) using MySQL 8

Comment: Ok and what is the result you want?

Comment: Both databases works perfectly on DB Fiddle.
I want to understand whether something wrong with my SQL editor or there's something else needed to be fixed

Comment: you are right seems like a bug, popsql seems to make out a >to  a =

Comment: yeah... gotta look into new GUI
thanks so much for your time!